# About Android Accessibility Talkback. Is there any talkback focus listener?

Tags: android, listview, listener, talkback

I am developing android photo application for visually impaired people.

Of course, my application is running in Talkback context.
Under Talkback context, when button is focused the system reads text of button.
[the green box represents the focused content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFvUE.png)

What I want to do is playing audio file when button is focused not text label of button. 
However, I cannot find any listener that detects button's focused state.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

DISCLAIMER: Things that happen on focus is potentially a major accessibility violation per [WCAG 2.0 - 3.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-receive-focus.html).  I would encourage you to rethink your design/do extensive user research, to ensure what you end up doing isn't just creating a frustrating user experience.  Not only that, but remember TalkBack is not the only Assistive technology, it strikes me that this mechanism could be incredibly frustrating for users using Switch Access and potentially completely broken for a BrailleBack user.

That being said, this is how you would accomplish this behavior:

You want to look at the callbacks available in [View.AccessibilityDelegate](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-receive-focus.html)

I believe you should be looking for code that looks something like this:

```
void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Attach this to the view that is receiving focus, or depending on which callback you use, you may be able to attach it to the layout containing a series of controls.

Now, I say "something like this" because there are a lot of different accessibility delegate callbacks, pre event firing, post event firing, things that allow you to tweak the event as it is populated up the view hierarchy, etc.  Which callback you choose depends on exactly when you want this to happen and the nature of things you may need to tweak about the AccessibilityEvent that is firing.

Comment: actually, I can't understand how to apply this code to my project. 
You mean I have to attach this code to my activity class?
Then how can I know which button is clicked? 

Simply, what I want to do :
When button1 is focused -> play A.mp3 file
When button2 is focused -> play B.mp3 file
(Is there any full-code example?)

Comment: clicked -> focused in previous comment

Comment: Thank you I did it. I set Accessibility delegate to the button!

Comment: You should accept the answer!  Keep things nice and clean.

Comment: I have a list of items where each item has a counter, since I won't use setLiveRegion in each item, I want to set it in the current selected item so the user gets advised of the changes in the counter that happens each ~30seconds. I think this use case is valid, don't you think?

Comment: @ChrisCM hey I have the same problem but I am not sure I undesrtand how to apply your code, could you please explain better, please?

Comment: This question could be asking for anything from a little more sample code up to an entire sample project. Ask another question and link it here and I'll answer it. But this is too vague of a question for me to want to edit an accepted answer.